# 'see' in continuous form to express having a romantic relationship

Tags: stative-verbs

The question is from [BBC Towards Advanced](https://www.bbc.co.uk/learningenglish/burmese/course/towards-advanced/unit-5/session-1)

> Q: In which of these sentences are Camille and Philippe in a romantic relationship?

> A) Camille has been seeing Philippe for a few months.
> B) Camille and Philippe were seeing each other for a year.

The right answer is A.

As I know 'see' is a stative verb, and stative verbs can be used in progressive tenses when they are used in set phrases. **Is it an excerpt of idiomatic language to say 'has been seeing' to express being in a romantic relationship?** The following sentence is from [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/tr/s%C3%B6zl%C3%BCk/ingilizce/see)

> How long has she been seeing him? (to have a romantic relationship with someone)

So if one writes 'Camille and Philippe were seeing each other for a year.' does it certainly not mean that they were in a romantic relationship? If so, what does it mean ?

Comment: Both A) and B).

Comment: Very often the organs being used are not the eyes.

Comment: It is A you can see by visiting the link and I'd love to hear why you think B (it's 'C' on the website) is also correct.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey For sure. But the question here is why is  'B'  incorrect? I suppose there is an idiomatic language here in the present perfect continuous tense, isn't there?

Comment: Nothing to do with 'idiom. Only sentence A includes the present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is:

In which of these sentences **are** Camille and Philippe in a romantic relationship?

The verb ('are') is in the present tense, so we need to find which of the two sentences discusses something which exists in the present.

Only A satisfies this requirement - '**has been** seeing' is in the **present perfect continuous** tense. This tense is used to discuss things which started in the past and have continued until **the present**, and are not yet finished.

In sentence B, the verb form is '**were** seeing' is in the **past continuous** tense, also known as the **past progressive** tense, We use this tense to talk about a continuing action or state that **was happening** at some point in the **past**.

Only sentence A says that Camille and Philippe are in a romantic relationship now, in the present.